# Android Intents - How to share text and image using an Intent to send a sms message in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I tried to share a text and attach an image to a sms message using an Intent from my application. It takes the message body but shows error, "unable to attach file" as a toast.

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
intent.putExtra("sms_body", message)
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment)
intent.type = "image/*"
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
activity?.startActivity(intent)
```

I tried lot of ways but had no luck yet.Where do you think i'm wrong? Is it imposible to share images with sms message? Some help is much appreciated.

Comment: First, use a concrete MIME type. It is your attachment, so it is your job to tell the other app what the MIME type is. Second, you are not granting read access, only write access (which probably the other app does not need). There might also be problems with `attachment` (e.g., a `Uri` with the `file` scheme), but we would need to know what `attachment` is to tell.

Comment: @CommonsWare attachment is a png image(Uri),  which works fine with facebook and instagram share

Comment: "attachment is a png image(Uri)" -- then use `image/png`, not `image/*`. Also, from the standpoint of the `Uri`, the scheme matters. `ACTION_SEND` is supposed to use a `content` scheme for `EXTRA_STREAM`. Typically, that means you should be using `FileProvider` to get that `Uri`.

Comment: Uri.parse(
            ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" +
                context.resources.getResourcePackageName(resID) + '/' +
                context.resources.getResourceTypeName(resID) + '/' +
                context.resources.getResourceEntryName(resID)

Comment: @CommonsWare this is how i get the Uri giving the resource id of the png image. I changed the mime type and given read permission as you said.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an `android.resource` `Uri` for `EXTRA_STREAM`. [`EXTRA_STREAM` is supposed to hold a `Uri` with a `content` scheme](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#EXTRA_STREAM). Not all applications will be able to use your `android.resource` `Uri`, because they are not expecting that scheme.

If you wish to improve compatibility, use `FileProvider` to share your PNG image using `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`, so you have a `content` `Uri` to use with `EXTRA_STREAM`.